# Button alignment will not sit where i tell it to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 boxes with roll over effects on a page, when someone mouses over the box it changes the content from a paragraph to a unordered list with a 'view more' button.

The problem is each box has a different amount of items in the list and the button is aligning at the end of the list where i am trying to align it to the very bottom of the box.

I have tried a few suggestions that i found looking through these forums but still cannot make it work. Could someone point me in the right direct? am i missing something?

The page is below, ideally i would like to align all the buttons to the bottom, in the same sort of place as the button appears in the first box.

http://wpdev.quadris.co.uk/what-we-do/

The code for the bit im working with is as follows

```css
 .box {

  cursor: pointer;
  height: 340px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .fa {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40%;
    left: 43%;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.box h2 {
      text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  left: 5%;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box p{
      text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.box .overbox p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.box .overbox {
  background-color: #424545;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
    padding: 30px 20px;

}

.box:hover .overbox { opacity: 1; }

.box .overtext {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
}

.box .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .title,
.box:focus .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}

.box .tagline {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color:#fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .tagline,
.box:focus .tagline {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  color: #fff;
}

.box .overbox  .btn-primary {
    position: relative;
 bottom: 0;
    background-color: #9e3039;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: none;

} 
.box .overbox .btn-primary a, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> <h2>Managed IT Solutions</h2>
    
<p>No matter what your IT requirement is, we can help.
Whether you are looking for a fully managed IT service or one tailored to supplement your internal team, we have a solution for you.
</p>
<i class="fa fa-gg"></i>
  <div class="overbox">
    <div class="title overtext"> 
  <ul>
   <li>Tailored IT Support</li>
   <li>Service Desk</li>
   <li>Networking Monitoring</li>
   <li>Managed Disaster Recovery</li>
   <li>IT PRocurement</li>
   <li>Managed Security</li>
   <li>Co-Location Services</li>
   <li>Hosted Services</li>
   <li>Domain Management</li>
   <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
  </ul>
      <div class="tagline overtext"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><a href="#">Find Out More</a></button> </div>

 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

PhilB

Comment: Position the buttons abolute, or use flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `height:90%` to your class `.text` thus this places your button at bottom of `.overbox`.

```
.box .title {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    height: 90%; /*Add this*/
}
```

Comment: @philb do accept or upvote the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: This is good solution, but OP should also add "overflow: scroll" to prevent hovering button over content (when list is too long)

Comment: @JuniorDev yes he could add overflow-y:scroll, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @frnt that worked perfect.

Am i correct in thinking then that before adding that line of code, the button was positioning itself at the end of the text, which has varying heights. By telling the text it is always 90% of its container, positioning the button relatively tells it to begin at 91%?

Sorry, i'm just trying to understand the theory instead of copy and pasting and taking it for granted.

Thanks! 

PhilB

Comment: Also, @JuniorDev..Which css class do i add the overflow to? I have added it to the .title class but now i have a scroll bar, even if the content doesnt over flow. 

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @philb and yes you are right your button gets placed at 91% i.e. after .text :-) and overflow-y:scroll is not needed. If you want then add that in .text section.

Comment: Thanks @frnt css positioning has always boggled my mind. i learned something. 

Regards,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

see code snippet below.

for the `button` to stay at the very bottom of the `.overbox` you need it to stay depending on the `overbox` .so, in HTML, move the `div` that contains the `button` out of the `.overtext` and put it as a direct child of `overbox` .

then set `position: absolute` to the `div` that contains the `button` ( `tagline` )  and `bottom:0` or `bottom:5px` as i have set in the below snippet ( so it's not exactly at the bottom )

hope it helps.

```css
.box {

  cursor: pointer;
  height: 340px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.box .fa {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 40%;
    left: 43%;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.box h2 {
      text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 24px;
  left: 5%;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}
.box p{
      text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    padding: 3%;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.box .overbox p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.box .overbox {
  background-color: #424545;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
    padding: 30px 20px 80px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}

.box:hover .overbox { opacity: 1; }

.box .overtext {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);

}

.box .title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .title,
.box:focus .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}

.box .tagline {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color:#fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .tagline,
.box:focus .tagline {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  color: #fff;
}

.box .overbox .tagline {
position:absolute;
 bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #9e3039;
    color: #fff;
    border-style: none;

} 
.box .overbox .tagline .btn-primary{
     background-color: #9e3039;
  }
.box .overbox .btn-primary a, a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> <h2>Managed IT Solutions</h2>
    
<p>No matter what your IT requirement is, we can help.
Whether you are looking for a fully managed IT service or one tailored to supplement your internal team, we have a solution for you.
</p>
<i class="fa fa-gg"></i>
  <div class="overbox">
    <div class="title overtext"> 
  <ul>
   <li>Tailored IT Support</li>
   <li>Service Desk</li>
   <li>Networking Monitoring</li>
   <li>Managed Disaster Recovery</li>
   <li>IT PRocurement</li>
   <li>Managed Security</li>
   <li>Co-Location Services</li>
   <li>Hosted Services</li>
   <li>Domain Management</li>
   <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
  </ul>
      

 </div>
    <div class="tagline overtext"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><a href="#">Find Out More</a></button> </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="box"> <h2>Managed IT Solutions</h2>
    
<p>No matter what your IT requirement is, we can help.
Whether you are looking for a fully managed IT service or one tailored to supplement your internal team, we have a solution for you.
</p>
<i class="fa fa-gg"></i>
  <div class="overbox">
    <div class="title overtext"> 
  <ul>
   <li>Tailored IT Support</li>
   <li>Service Desk</li>
   <li>Networking Monitoring</li>
   <li>Managed Disaster Recovery</li>
   <li>IT PRocurement</li>
   <li>Managed Security</li>
   <li>Co-Location Services</li>
   <li>Hosted Services</li>
   <li>Domain Management</li>
   <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
          <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
          <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
          <li>Security Vulnerability Scanning</li>
       
  </ul>
     

 </div>
     <div class="tagline overtext"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><a href="#">Find Out More</a></button> </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box"> <h2>Managed IT Solutions</h2>
    
<p>No matter what your IT requirement is, we can help.
Whether you are looking for a fully managed IT service or one tailored to supplement your internal team, we have a solution for you.
</p>
<i class="fa fa-gg"></i>
  <div class="overbox">
    <div class="title overtext"> 
  <ul>
   <li>Tailored IT Support</li>
   <li>Service Desk</li>
   <li>Networking Monitoring</li>
   <li>Managed Disaster Recovery</li>

  </ul>
      

 </div>
    <div class="tagline overtext"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><a href="#">Find Out More</a></button> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mihai T,

I tried you're method, and it did effect the button but it sort of positioned it in the centre of the container when i did so.

Thank you though,

Comment: well in my snippet everything works fine. are you sure you copied and changed everything i added/changed to your code ?

Comment: Hi, yes, upon reflection i found i had added to the wrong CSS file. I do apologise. It doesnt quite position it in the same place, but it does indeed work better than my original version. 

Both answers provided work.

Phil

Comment: glad i could help. too bad you didn't notice that sooner :)) would've loved some points :)) . cheers ! :D